# H+ concentration decreasing over time reasoning in weak acid strong base titration

Tags: equilibrium

We know that, when $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is just present in water, it is in equilibirum with water and having some $\ce{H+}$ dissociated to give some $\mathrm{pH}$ to it. Now when we start adding $\ce{NaOH}$ to it, we say as $\ce{OH-}$ is having tendency to react with $\ce{H+}$ formed intially, so now onwards $\ce{H+}$ starts decreasing, but by Le Chatlier this means weak acid should increase its dissociation. The $\mathrm{pH}$ is given by $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a + \log\frac{\ce{[salt]}}{\ce{[acid]}} $. But how to show that net $\ce{H+}$ concentration will decrease  at any time? So that $\mathrm{pH}$ will keep on increasing, as its not easy to see that $\ce{H+}$ conc will decrease over time from just the two chemical equations given by -
$$ \ce{CH3COOH <<=>  CH3COO- +  H+}$$
$$ \ce{H+ + OH- <<=> H2O}$$
Because forming rate of $\ce{H+}$ from $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is different from reacting rate with $\ce{OH-}$ isn't?

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/27802/79678.

Comment: There i am not getting how there are two more equlibirum setup being considered , also there also its being said that as H+ is consuming , so it makes H+ decreasing , which is not answering my question :( @EdV specially my reason of rate thing which is not very obvious

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: By providing H+, that was consumed by OH-, there cannot be reached the original concentration , as ratio of acid and it's salt is changing. Therefore pH increases. // Thoughts about reaction rates are misleading. Acidobasic reactions are very fast and when solution is properly mixed, it can be considered to be already at equilibrium with negligible error.

Comment: @Poutnik surely i will use those stuff for fomatting thanks , The ratio of acid and salt, that was used in the pH formula isnt? , you are saying that with respect to formula isnt ?  How do you prove that lets say intially there were x moles of H+ , after a bit titration occured it will never reach greater than x moles of H+ ? Volume remains same , so concentration directly depends on moles of H+ . In my doubt above i didnt mention any equation of acid base isnt? Or you mean there are three reactions going on inside , two are equlibrium ones and one is acid base ?or there are more than that ?

Comment: And i need to consider the effect of  all? Which i didnt did in above ?

Comment: rhetorical question: Cant there be the same pH with different ratio of conjugate acid/base?  //At any point of titration, the following conditions have to be met: 1/ charge balance equation - net charge is zero 2/ molar amount balance equations like total acid concentration = sum of c. of conj. acid and base. 3/ acid dissociation equilibrium equation 4/ water autodissociation equilibrium equation.

Comment: I think i will get the answer if you may provide the above four equations which you are talking off Sir ? As i didnt derive at all the formula with the way you are saying , i will definitely want to see how its shows it , so may you for once please give the equations(mathematical equations the four conditions you said above just wrt to the above problem ?) @Poutnik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135839/discussion-between-poutnik-and-paracetamol).

Answer (score 2):

If starting generally with [Le Chatelier's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle), the reaction of the system against the external change compensates it just *partially*. If we increase pressure of a gaseous reaction mixture in equilibrium two times, it will react to partially decrease the pressure, but will not return to the original pressure.

Back to the reaction: Note that the net reaction during the titration is:

$$\ce{CH3COOH(aq) + OH-(aq) -> CH3COO-(aq) + H2O(l)} \tag{1}$$

As you have written yourself, the equation for $\mathrm{pH}$ is:

$$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log{\frac{[\ce{CH3COO-}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]}}\tag{2}$$

which can be directly derived from the dissociation equilibrium reaction:

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{CH3COO-}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]}\tag{3}$$

belonging to the equilibrium reaction:

$$\ce{CH3COOH(aq) <=> CH3COO-(aq) + H+(aq)} \tag{4}$$

which partially resupplies H+(aq) ions consumed by the neutralization reaction

$$\ce{H+(aq) + OH-(aq) -> H2O}\tag{5}$$

which has its own equilibrium equation

$$K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]\tag{6}$$

The reaction (4) resupplies H+ just partially, because as the titration is progressing, the value of the logarithm in (2) increases and therefore $\mathrm{pH}$ increases.

Comment: What about the equlibirum reaction of OH- reacting with CH3COOH ? I mean you have written that in top but that is by combining the below two reactions in the post of yours Sir . i mean as a separate reaction it will happens too isnt ? We already have CH3COOH and H+ inside the container when OH- is coming it will react with both isnt ? So it will have some other equlibirum constant isnt ? Why we are combining it , as its actually happening as a reaction eith the other two going on

Comment: That equilibrium is not independent and it's eq. constant is the reciprocal value of the acetate basicity constant, i.e. 1/Kb=Ka/Kw.

Comment: I see so actually there are three reactions going on two are eqb ones ch3cooh disscoation and ch3cooh reaction with oh- and one is water one , but here the thing is that one eqb is depedent on another hence we write just two and its sufficient for calculations ? Am i right ? Thats what books do by not writing some equations because its dependent on others which we already wrote? @Poutnik Sir

Comment: Also @Poutnik Sir The answer given here for a question which was told to me to be seen regarding my query ,  do you think its fully correct Sir ? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/112360/123521

Comment: Sir may you once check this too ?

Comment: Checking it and telling you it is right or wrong will not do for you any good. You go to check it and realize *why* it is right or wrong.